# NIntegrate with periodic sharp peaks

Tags: numerical-integration

I have a function with periodic sharp peak, say (analytic integration is not possible):

```
Exp[-20 Sin[x]^2 -20 Sin[y]^2]
```

and I need to perform numerical integral over it. I know for singularities `NIntegrate` can be speed up with `Exclusions`, but does that work with regular peaks as well? Will the result be affected?

Edit:
I tried comparing the following:

```
f1[t_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[
  Exp[-10 Sin[\[Pi] x]^2 - 10 Sin[\[Pi] y]^2 - 
    t^2 (x - y)^2], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, x, 5}, 
  Exclusions -> IntegerQ[x] || IntegerQ[y], 
  Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
AbsoluteTiming[Plot[f1[t], {t, 0, 1}]]
f2[t_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[
  Exp[-10 Sin[\[Pi] x]^2 - 10 Sin[\[Pi] y]^2 - 
    t^2 (x - y)^2], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
  Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
AbsoluteTiming[Plot[f2[t], {t, 0, 1}]]
```

The second one is much faster (47s vs 21s). Why?

Edit 2: In short, I would like to know how to speed up `NIntegral` on this kind of integrand, and I assumed that that means I will need to have some basic understanding of how things work.

Comment: What does `t` do?

Comment: @Bill It's not a typo. Documentation `NIntegrate`states "NIntegrate[f,{x,Subscript[x, 0],Subscript[x, 1],\[Ellipsis],Subscript[x, k]}] tests for singularities in a one-dimensional integral at each of the intermediate points Subscript[x, i]."

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Yes, that is indeed intended. However, I did try the calculation without that specification, and that resulted in a significant speedup.

Comment: I don't see a big difference between `AbsoluteTiming[f1[0]]` which results in `0.67821, 3.36871}` and `AbsoluteTiming[f2[0]]` which outputs `{0.516779, 3.36872}`. The integrand has no singularity, so `Exclusions -> IntegerQ[x] || IntegerQ[y]` only eats time.